# JSON support over various hosting companies

Tags: php, json

I am working on a PHP class that will be executed on various hosting servers all across the net. This file will communicate with my server. I am planning to use JSON for this communication as JSON has native support from PHP 5.2.

But before I start working the class using JSON I wanted to know if the hosting companies may prefer to disable JSON for some reason or will they let it enabled. I don't want my class to be useless on most of the servers just because the hosting company has disabled JSON for some reason. Although I don't see any security risk or any other reason why JSOn may be disabled.

Please let me know the possibilities of JSON being disabled by the hosting companies for any reason.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's disabled you could utilize various emulations for JSON encoding/decoding as fallback:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.json.html
- http://upgradephp.berlios.de/
- http://pear.php.net/PHP_Compat
- http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html
- http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON

Just define a simple wrapper function where the provided class doesn't do so itself.

```
if (!function_exists("json_decode")) {
   require("Services/JSON.php");
   function json_decode($s) {
       $json = new Services_JSON;
       return $json->decode($s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see **any** reason why JSON functions would be disabled, and I know of no hosting provider who does so. JSON is pure formatting - and therefor no greater security risk then a plain text.

Comment: Yeah, but I have read across the net that some hosting companies just install the PHP with default switches ending up disabling most of the useful functions. Then users have to call them up asking for the feature  to be enabled... Thank you for your reply...